# Returning Singleton beans depending on input in Spring

Tags: java, spring, singleton

Let's say I have the following:

```
@Component
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ToolFactory {

    public Tool getTool(String type) {
        return StaticToolProvider.getTool(type);
    }
}
```

This class will be injected elsewhere and called like this:

`Tool screwdriver = ToolFactory.getTool("screwdriver")`

If the tools can be screwdriver, hammer, or wrench, I want Spring to create Singleton beans for each, and return them when `getTool()` is called. I believe `@Provides @Singleton` would do this in Guice, but how could I do it here?

Comment: give details. what you want to do

Comment: I will only ever return a screwdriver, hammer, or wrench, but I don't want new prototype beans returned for every call. I only want 3 beans to only ever be created, but I want them created as `getTool()` is called, or the existing Singleton returned if it exists.

Comment: You have screwdriver, hammer bean which implements Tool?

Comment: add more code and ask what you have and what you want

Comment: u can define Tools as components, and autowire to your factory class. And depending on your logic, return the required instance. you can also take a look at `FactoryBean` and see if it helps in your scenario

Comment: Inject the three beans into your ToolFactory, and use `if` or `switch` to return the appropriate one based on the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create map with all needed beans. Map will be `singleton` by default and `unmodifiable` to prevent anyone changing it by mistake. If you need hammer to be spring bean just `autowire` it, if no you can just use regular object creation using `new`

```
@Configuration
class Config {

   @Bean
   Map<String, Tool> tools(Hammer hammer) {
     Map<String, Tool> map = new HashMap<>();
     map.put("hammer", hammer);
     //map.put("hammer",new Hammer())
     return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
   }

}


@Component
public class Container {

    private Map<String, Tool> tools;

    @Autowired
    public Container(Map<String, Tool> tools) {
        this.tools = tools;
    }

    Tool getTool(String tool) {
        return tools.get(tool);
    }
}
```